# Issue with flipping object with 2 image in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, flip

So I was creating a Player Object in Unity by adding 2 images and creating a single character.
Now the problem is when I flip it 180 degrees, the object moves forward for some reason whereas when 
I remove one of the image and change it to just a single image and then flip it , it works.
How do I fix the rotation problem??

Here is the problem visually:

- [Before flipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAwoJ.png)
- [After flipping 180 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSSe4.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the transform of the `MCCHARACTER` does not change when you rotate it, so I think child objects of `MCCHARACTER` does not have zero local positions.

I mean you should change position of all child objects of `MCCHARACTER` to zero.